# How do this consult for refinancing dynamically?

Tags: sql, select, relationship, relation

I have this table HistoricRefinancing:

```
id authorization_id refinancing_id
1     1                  7
2     3                  7
3     5                  6
```

I just need this:

```
id authorization_id refinancing_id
1     1                  7
2     3                  7
```

and this:

```
id authorization_id refinancing_id
3     5                  6
```

How I get the refinancing that contain each authorization?
I do select * from HistoricRefinancing where (refinancinfg_id = 7) for example, but how do it dynamically?

Comment: when you say dynamically are you talking about parameterizing your select statement? For ex) SELECT * FROM HistoricRedinancing WHERE refinancing_id = @p_refinancing_id

Comment: Yep, I guess that this